# Over-represented categories in one sample

Tags: hypothesis-testing, proportion

Suppose we have a sample with $n$ discrete categories; e.g., in R:

```
my_sample <- c(rep("A", 64), rep("B", 4), rep("C", 153), rep("D", 131), rep("E", 43))
table(my_sample)
my_sample
 A   B   C   D   E 
64   4 153 131  43
```

I wonder how to statistically test which category is statistically over-represented in a sample?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have population figures, you can't tell which category is over-represented.

However, if you are willing to assume some distribution in the population (e.g. that all categories have the same number) then you can use a one sample chi-square.

Comment: +1 you can only say “over represented” if you know/define what it means to be “normally” represented. It’s much like a question about “outliers”: first you have to decide what’s an in-lier. “Statistics” doesn’t do it for you.